# Static analysis tool that understands COM?

Tags: c++, com, static-analysis

I've looked at a couple of (expensive) Static Analysis tools for C/C++ that check STL, but they do not understand Microsoft COM. One at least can generate false error messages due to COM reference counting.  I found a mono project that does static analysis on code with .NET assemblies (//www.mono-project.com/Gendarme).   But what I didn't find was anything that does static analysis and understands COM. What I really want is a tool that can diagnose COM threading related potential deadlocks, that works with Visual Studio 2008 C++ code.  Does anyone know of anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that if you are looking for detected of threading issues static analysis is not the best way to do it.
This is the realm of dynamic analysis tools.
In particular, Intel Parallel Studio has such dynamic analysis capabilities